# Atualizar várias divs em uma só página

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma página onde preciso atualizar algumas `divs` com informações vindas do banco. Com isso estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<div id='diva'>conteúdo a</div>
<div id='divb'>conteúdo b</div>
<div id='divc'>conteúdo c</div>
```

E assim por diante. No jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("#diva").load(location.href+" #diva");
  $("#divb").load(location.href+" #divb");
  $("#divc").load(location.href+" #divc");
}, 1000);
```

Só que percebi que ao ficar muito alguns minutos na mesma página, a página pisca e depois some os dados, voltando logo em seguida. Teria algum meio de minimizar esse impacto?

Comment: Os dados aparecem e depois eles somem e aparecem novamente, ou eles só são mostrados depois?

Comment: aparecem e somem... depois aparecem,.... aí a página para de piscar e volta a piscar novamente....

Comment: No fim do código do `setInterval` (dentro dele ainda), adicione `console.log("Load")`. Veja no console quantas vezes a mensagem aparece no console quando a página carrega.

Comment: Coloco antes ou depois do 1000?

Comment: Antes, "(dentro dele ainda)".

Comment: Coloquei dessa forma: console.log("Load")
}, 1000);

Comment: aparece a cada 1 seg..

Comment: Acredito que se eu mudar para 10 segundos, diminuirá esse impacto, certo? sobre a estrutura do jquery, está correto colocar várias divs da forma como foi colocado?

Comment: E precisas de mudar/carregar essas divs todas a cada segundo? (1000 ms)

Comment: Pois é... uma falha minha... mas corrigi e coloquei 15 segundos... a ideia inicial era para que cada mensagem que aparecesse, atualizasse automaticamente. 15 segundos acredito que esteja bom, porém se eu estiver errado, ficarei feliz em ser corrigido :)